# dplyr bizarre ERROR: group_by()%>%summarise() outputs just one line

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm having problem with this 'textbook' example on how to aggreate data by group:

```
library(dplyr)    
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(sum(Sepal.Length))
```

I'm getting different results on diffent R/Rstudio sessions on the same computer.

Session A: the above code returns a one line output:

```
  sum(Sepal.Length)
1             876.5
```

Session B: same code returns the expected output:

```
     Species sum(Sepal.Length)
1     setosa             250.3
2 versicolor             296.8
3  virginica             329.4
```

In session A I had open some other dataset and libraries before. However I made sure I executed **library(dplyr)** imediattely before the **group_by()%>%summarise()**

What on earth can be happening?

EDIT: based on comments bellow, I double checked, and, yes: I'm calling **library(plyr)** before **library(dplyr)**. And yes, the suggestion **library(dplyr)
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(sum(Sepal.Length))**

Comment: `dplyr::summarise()`

Comment: You loaded `plyr` after `dplyr` and masked `dplyr::summarize` (and ignored the warning that told you about it). If you had already loaded `dplyr`, calling `library()` again right before the command won't do anything.

Comment: tks, but I'm not. I loaded  **library(plyr)** first and **library(dplyr)** second. As I said in the question, I even reloaded  **library(dplyr)**  to make sure

Comment: And, yes: **iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% dplyr::summarise(sum(Sepal.Length))** does work.

Comment: If `dplyr::summarise()` works then it almost certainly is an issue of `plyr::summarise()` masking `dplyr::summarise()`. As @Gregor said, calling `library("dplyr")` again will not make a difference. What happens if you run `detach(package:plyr)` and try your code again?

Comment: "reloading" does nothing. It also could be something other than `plyr`... `Hmisc` has a `summarize` with a "z", and there could be others too. You can always run `searchpaths()` to see it `dplyr` is before `plyr` or not.